# Stop the communication between react components using mufa after a condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, publish-subscribe, mufa

I am using the sub/pub pattern via [mufa](http://npmjs.com/package/mufa) to make communication between React components instead of props. Then, we will mitigate the logic in the Parent component (as you will notice that in the following snippet).

```js
const {on, fire} = mufa;
class Input extends React.Component {
   
   onChange(event) {
     fire('input_change', event.target.value);
   }

   render() {
     return <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
   }
}

class Label extends React.Component {
   state= {text: ""};
   componentDidMount() {
     on('input_change', this.onInputChange.bind(this));
   }

   onInputChange(inputValue) {
      this.setState({text: inputValue});
      // I need code to stop calling this method when inputValue reaches 10 characters. 
       
    }

   render() {
     return <label > {this.state.text} </label>
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
   // No logic here thanks to the Sub/Pub pattern. 
   render() {
     return (
        <div>
           <Label />
           <Input/>
    
        </div>
     )
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/abdennour/mufa/ddf78fd9/cdn/mufa-latest.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" ></div>
```

My concern is how to stop this communication between `Label` and `Input` when the input value reaches 10 chars.

I tried this:

```
   onInputChange(inputValue) {


      if (inputValue.length <= 10 )  // <-- I add this.

         this.setState({text: inputValue});
    }
```

However , this condition does not prevent the calling of `onInputChange`. My target is to stop this subscription( to `input_change` event) when the input reaches 10 chars  immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `mufa` has a way to unsubscribe like this:

```js
const mufa = new Mufa();
const {on, fire, unsub} = mufa;
class Input extends React.Component {
   
   onChange(event) {
     fire('input_change', event.target.value);
   }

   render() {
     return <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
   }
}

class Label extends React.Component {
   state= {text: ""};
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sub = null;
   }
   componentDidMount() {
     this.sub = on('input_change', this.onInputChange.bind(this));
 
   }

   onInputChange(inputValue) {

      if(inputValue.length >= 10) {
       unsub(this.sub);
       return;
      };

      this.setState({text: inputValue});
      // I need code to stop calling this method when inputValue reaches 10 characters. 
       
    }

   render() {
     return <label > {this.state.text} </label>
   }
}

class App extends React.Component {
   // No logic here thanks to the Sub/Pub pattern. 
   render() {
     return (
        <div>
           <Label />
           <Input/>
    
        </div>
     )
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://abdennour.github.io/mufa/mufa-latest.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" ></div>
```

Comment:  You are genius .. It works like a charm .. Thank you so much. 
I am not able to vote up your answer ; It seems stackoverflow requires 15 pts at least. Anyway , many thanks.

Comment: `unsub` or `off` : The two methods are valid according to [documentation](http://elegance.abdennoor.com/mufa/#off)