# How to send form input data from one component to another component in react js?

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-router

I have an input form that retrieves the dish details from an api, and the user can select the quantity, based on the quantity total price of the dish changes.Along with that he can select Home_delivery or Pickup.After selecting and clicking next,that data has to be sent to another page to display what the user has selcted for confirmation,and on this page users enters his details to proceed to next step.

Currently i am sending the form details to 2nd page in url but if we change the values (for eg: total price from 250 to 200), it is displaying 200 on 2nd Page

*page 1*

https://imagebin.ca/v/3FVPLAQDOLgV

*page 2*

https://imagebin.ca/v/3FVPiaEg3qJy

**DishItem.js**

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   quantity: null,
   delivery: null,
   total_cost: null,
   time: null,
   dish_name: null
 }
}

componentWillMount() {
 this.setState({quantity: 1, dish_name : this.props.dish.name, time: this.props.dish.preparation_end_time,
    total_cost: this.props.dish.net_cost})
}

handleChangeInQuantity(value) {
 var total_cost = 0;
 total_cost = value * this.props.dish.net_cost;
 this.setState({quantity: value, total_cost: total_cost});
}

handleChangeInDeliveryMode(value) {
 this.setState({delivery: value});
}

saveAndContinue(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 browserHistory.push('/confirm_order/'+ this.state.dish_name + '/' + this.state.quantity + '/' + this.state.total_cost + '/' + this.state.delivery);
}
render() {
 var date = new Date(this.props.dish.preparation_end_time);
 var hour = date.getHours();
 var minute = date.getMinutes();
 var period = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
 return (
  <div>
   <h3>{this.props.dish.name}{this.props.dish.dish_content}</h3>
   Total- {this.state.total_cost}
   <Quantity change_in_quantity={this.handleChangeInQuantity.bind(this)} />
   <h4>Food Will be ready by <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> <span>{hour}:{minute} {period}</span> Today<br/></h4>
   <Delivery change_in_delivery_mode=    {this.handleChangeInDeliveryMode.bind(this)} />
   {this.props.dish.hub_name}<br />
   <button className="btn btn-default" onClick= {this.saveAndContinue.bind(this)}>Next</button>
 </div>
)
}
```

**Confirm_Order.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class Confirm_Order extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          name: '',
          phone: ''
        }
      }
      saveName(e) {
        this.setState({name: e.target.value})
      }
      savePhone(e) {
        this.setState({phone: e.target.value})
      }
      handleFormSubmission(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
      }
      render() {
        let dish = this.props.params;
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>{dish.dishname}</h2>
            <h4>{dish.quantity} Plates | Rs {dish.total_cost} | {dish.delivery} at </h4>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmission.bind(this)}>
              <div>
                <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.saveName.bind(this)}/>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Phone</label>
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.savePhone.bind(this)}/>
              </div>
              <button type="submit">Request OTP</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

**Routes.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Router, Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
    import App from './App';
    import Home from './Components/Home';
    import NotFound from './Components/NotFound';
    import Confirm_Order from './Components/Confirm_Order';

    export default (props) => (
      <Router {...props}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} >
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="/confirm_order/:dishname/:quantity/:total_cost/:delivery" component={Confirm_Order} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
```

Comment: If you see your application growing and requiring shared state, you should consider using a state management library etc Redux

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42771843/stop-the-communication-between-react-components-using-mufa-after-a-condition) , the guy who asks the question makes communications beteween components smoothly.

Comment: @user1185197 I don't know about redux,started learning react just a week back.Can this be done without using Redux?

Comment: Yes, of course. Look into the flux architecture, but please give yourself a favour and get introduced to redux, mobx

Comment: ok will look into it,but i thought of another way sending the form details from DishItem.js to its parent Home.js.But i couldn't figure out a way of sending that from Home.js to Confirm_Order.js